# How can one justify if the graph is planar from adjacency matrix?

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, graph-theory, planar-graphs, eulerian-path

Given an adjacency matrix of a graph $G$, I was asked to do the following without drawing the graph:

A) Find the vertex of largest degree.

B) Does the graph have an Euler Circuit?

C) Is the graph Planar?

---

I did A and B. How can one justify if the graph is planar from adjacency matrix?

Comment: You could try using a theorem that gives criteria for planarity. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Planar_graph

Comment: Which adjacency matrix are you given?

Comment: @Semiclassical I was asking for a general result. i.e. given any adjacency matrix can we comment on the planarity of the graph?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are some simple conditions which, if transgressed, would mean that the graph is non-planar but **in general** there is nothing which could easily determine whether the graph is planar.

Since you said 'without drawing the graph' can we assume that the matrix is fairly small?

For a small number of vertices (e.g. $6$) it is easy to check whether or not the graph   contains $K_{3,3}$ or a subgraph homeomorphic to $K_5$.

The reference you have already been given

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Planar_graph

should be useful for the simple conditions.

Answer (score 1):

If you have adjancency matrix like this one $$A = \pmatrix{0&1&1&1&1&1 &1\\1&0&1&1&1&1&1\\1&1&0&1&1&1&1 \\1&1&1&0&1&1&1 \\1&1&1&1&0&1&1\\1&1&1&1&1&0&1\\1&1&1&1&1&1&0}$$
then this graph is clearly not planar since all degrees are $6$ and in planar graph must exists vertex of degree less than $6$.

Probably you have some matrix from which is easy to deduce some numercial estimation which says that it is not planar, like $e> 3n-6$ or something like this.